# Can anyone explain how this functional program work?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def apply_twice(func,arg):
   return func(func(arg))

def add_five(x):
   return x+5

print (apply_twice(add_five,10))
```

The output I get is 20.

This one is actually confusing me like how is it working.Can anybody explain me how this is working by breaking it down

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `apply_twice(func,arg)` takes two arguments, a function object `func` and an argument to pass to the function `func` called `arg`.

In Python, functions can easily be passed around to other functions as arguments, ***they are not treated differently*** than any other argument type (i.e [first class citizens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)).

Inside `apply_twice`, `func` is called twice in the line:

```
func(func(arg))
```

Which, alternatively, can be viewed in a more friendly way as:

```
res = func(arg)  
func(res)
```

If you replace `func` with the name of the function passed in `add_five` you get the following:

```
res = add_five(arg)  # equals: 15
add_five(res)        # result: 20
```

which, of course, returns your expected result.

The key point to remember from this is that you shouldn't think of functions in `Python` as some special construct, functions are objects just like `int`s, `lists`s and everything else is.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding the code it executes as follows, starting with the `print` call:

`apply_twice(add_five,10))`

`add_five(add_five(10)) # add_five(10) = 15`

`add_five(15) # add_five(15) = 20`

Which gives you the result: 20.

When `apply_twice` is called, you are passing in a function object and a value. As you can see in the `apply_twice` definition, where you see `func` that is substituted with the function object passed to it (in this case, `add_five`). Then, starting with the inner `func(arg)` call, evaluate the result, which is then passed to `add_five` again, in the outer `return func( ... )` call.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand here is that

> apply_twice(func,arg)

is a higher function which accepts two arguments (another function named `func`  and an argument `arg`). The way it works is that it first evaluate the value of the other function, then use the value as an argument inside the higher function.

remember we have a function `add_five(x)` which add 5 to the argument supply in it...
then this function `add_five(x)` is then passed as an argument to another function called 
`apply_twice_(func,arg)` which return `func(func(arg))`.

now splitting  `func(func(arg))` we have 
 `func(arg)` #lets called it `a`
then `func(func(arg))==func(a`) since `a = func(agr)`

and `(a)` is our `add_five(x)` function, after it add 5, then the value we got is re-used as another fresh argument to add another 5 to it, that is why we have 20 as our result.

Another example is:

```
def test(func, arg):
  return func(func(arg))

def mult(x):
  return x * x

print(test(mult, 2))
```

which give 16 as result.